# Pass values from BackgroundWorker DoWork to BackgroundWorker Completed

Tags: vb.net, variables, backgroundworker, pass-by-value, byval

How do I pass a value from `BackgroundWorker` `DoWork` to `BackgroundWorker` `Completed`? Since `BackgroundWorker` `Completed` is not called by `BackgroundWorker` `DoWork` I am not sure how to do this except declare a `public variable`. Essentially, I want `BackgroundWorker` `Completed` to accept through `ByVal` a variable from `BackgroundWorker` `DoWork`.

Comment: I agree with you that since you are not guaranteed to execute on the same thread that the safest way to "share" the data is to put it in a public variable and then use some thread-safe access mechanism to ensure there is no deadlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare your `DoWork` function, note that it has some handy arguments built in :

```
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) _
                                                  Handles backgroundWorker1.DoWork
```

and also note similar arguments for the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler :

```
Private Sub backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                          ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
                                       Handles backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
```

Critically, you have access to `e.Result`, which can be any object, in the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`, and also `e.Result` in your `DoWorkEventArgs` - the latter is passed to the former when the method completes so at the end of your worker method just set :

```
e.Result = myResult
```

and then in your `RunWorkerCompleted` handler you can access it also via :

```
if e.Result = (whatever) then 
    .... etc
```

---

**Reference :**

[RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result Property : MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[DoWorkEventArgs.Result Property : MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.result%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)